# Passing props form redux store to child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm trying to avoid manually subscribing to the redux store in every component that needs access to it. Meaning, I want to avoid doing a `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(component)` in every component that needs access to store. My current strategy is having an App.js component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import * as AllStudentActions from '../actions/StudentActions';
import * as AllEmployerActions from '../actions/EmployerActions';
import * as AllRecruiterActions from '../actions/RecruiterActions';
import * as AllUserActions from '../actions/UserActions';
import * as AllSocketActions from '../actions/SocketActions';


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>This is app</h1>
                {/* {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, this.props)} */}
                {/* {React.cloneElement({...this.props}.children, {...this.props})} */}
                {React.cloneElement({...{...this.props}.children}.children, {...this.props})}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        jobs: state.jobs,
        employers: state.employers,
        recruiters: state.recruiters,
        user: state.user,
        students: state.students,
        socket: state.socket
    };
}


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: {
            userActions: bindActionCreators(AllUserActions, dispatch),
            studentActions: bindActionCreators(AllStudentActions, dispatch),
            employerActions: bindActionCreators(AllEmployerActions, dispatch),
            socketActions: bindActionCreators(AllSocketActions, dispatch),
            recruiterActions: bindActionCreators(AllRecruiterActions, dispatch)
        }
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

thats using React.cloneElement to basically "sprinkle down" props from redux store unto child components. I got this idea from Wess Bos's redux tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2IOqeubsBw&t=388s&ab_channel=WesBos).

However, I'm also using react router, as shown in my here in my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from  './components/App';

import WaveyText from './components/WaveyText';

import Main2 from './components/Main2';


// import pages components



// router dependencies
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './store';





const router = (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          
          <Route path="/" component={App}>
              <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={WaveyText}></Route>
                  <Route exact path= "/test"> <div> Test </div> </Route>
              </Switch>
          </Route>

        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
)

render(router, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and the components being passed into Route aren't connecting to the store. At the very least, App.js should render, and in the react dev tools I should see the default state of the redux store in the App.js component, yet that isn't happening. Obviously, the child components under App.js aren't being connected either.

I'm not sure if its a problem with how I'm using react router, or my technique of wrapping the components in App.js.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI for a I had previously thought it was better to pass the state down, but the redux docs actually recommend connecting at more points: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store

Comment: Yeah, I'm starting to realise that's a better option as well. Thanks for the comment, and article.